# I cannot understand the compiler C++ switch, invalid operand error

Tags: c++, switch-statement, operator-keyword, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float Litr;
    int opcja;

    cout << "Konwerter" << endl;
    switch(opcja){

case 1:
    cout << "Litr na barylke amerykanska i galon amerykanski" << endl;
    cin >> Litr;
    cout << Litr << " litrow to " << Litr * 159 << " barylek i " << Litr * 3,78 << "galonow.";
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error in line 16 (e.g
cout << Litr << " litrow to " << Litr * 159 << " barylek i " << Litr * 3,78 << "galonow.";
)

||=== Build: Debug in aeiou (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users*file loaction*\main.cpp|16|error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char [9]' to binary 'operator<<'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Don't understand what's wrong and what compiler tries to tell me.

Comment: Use decimal dot, not decimal comma.

Comment: It worked, kind of a stupid question, should I delete it?

Comment: Yep, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, they are simple syntactic errors. When you have to express a decimal number in C ++ you have to use the "." and not the ",". There was also the problem that the command to execute was not asked in input and a simple cin was inserted.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int opcja;
    
    cout << "Konwerter: ";
    cin >> opcja;
    
    switch(opcja) {
        case 1: {
            float Litr;
            cout << "Litr na barylke amerykanska i galon amerykanski" << endl;
            cin >> Litr;
            cout << Litr << " litrow to " << Litr * 159 << " barylek i " << Litr * 3.78 << "galonow.";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sort of a stupid problem, you even sorted my code to be less messy! Thank you for your effort, nicely explained.

Comment: Imagine, I always try to point out how important a good indentation and self-documented code is to clarify even the biggest problems that maybe turn out to be stupid. Feel free to contact me with any problems :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma in 3,78 should be `3.78`

See here for an [example](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F*%20pow%20example%20*%2F%0A%23include%20%3Cstdio.h%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F*%20printf%20*%2F%0A%23include%20%3Cmath.h%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F*%20pow%20*%2F%0A%0Aint%20main%20()%0A%7B%0A%20%20system(%22ls%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%200%3B%0A%7D) based on your code